# How to fix: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I encounter error while compiling the code:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

The funny thing is that it is working on a different machine.
I see a couple of other posts about this error but different cases or the answer is just some generic stuff that I already tried (clearing cache, restarting, re-install pods).

I have Xcode 13.4.1.

```
private var deleteDisposable: Disposable? 
    func startDeleting() {

deleteDisposable = Observable<Int> // error message pointing on equal sign 
            .interval(.seconds(60), scheduler: Schedulers.serialBackground)
            .map { [weak self] _ in self?.dao.count() ?? 0 }
            .flatMap { [weak self] number in
                if number! <= 10 {
                    return self?.deleteOld() ?? Completable.empty()
                } else {
                    return self?.delete() ?? Completable.empty()
                }
            }
            .subscribe(on: Schedulers.concurrentBackground)
            .observe(on: Schedulers.serialBackground)
            .subscribe()

                deleteDisposable?.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

When I get rid of the `if` statement block, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

---

@Edit

The body of `deleteOld()` and `delete()` methods are similar:

```
     func delete() -> Completable {
        Completable.create { [weak self] observer in
            self?.firstDao.delete()
            self?.secondDao.delete()
            observer(.completed)
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the return types of your `deleteOld` and `delete` functions? And what is the type of `Completable.empty()`?

Comment: Why use `[weak self]` with `flatMap`?

Comment: @HangarRash, I add code of the corresponding methods to the question. The returning types seems the same, `Completable` in `delete()` methods and `Completable` in `Completable.empty()`, or I  misunderstood something.

Comment: The `[weak self]` I use for weak reference to the corresponding object for better memory management, I read somewhere that's good practice, it is not?

Comment: Try to specify the signature of the closure inside `flatMap`, i.e. `(number: Int) -> Completable`.

Comment: Does `count()` return an `Int` or an `Int?`?

Comment: @LouisLac yep, your suggestion is working, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I see Louis Lac already answered the question in the comments. In general, whenever you see `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` It means either your types are wrong, or that the system can't infer the type of something. The answer is always to add the types of everything.

To answer your question in the comments... Inside the flatMap, it would be best if you didn't reference self at all, but if you have to reference it, use `weak` or `unowned`. This is because the Observable chain is holding a reference to whatever you use in the closures, and the dispose bag is holding a reference to the observable chain, and your class object holds a reference to the dispose bag... Therefore if you made `self` strong, your class would be holding a reference to itself and therefore never delete.

Some other issues with the code...

- The `subscribe(on:)` does nothing useful. Since you passed the serialBackground scheduler to the interval, it will emit into that thread.
- The `observe(on:)` does nothing useful. Since the `.subscribe()` is empty, there is no code to run on the serialBackground scheduler.
- The function name is misleading. The function doesn't "start deleting". Rather it sets up the deletion system. Calling `dispose()` on the `deleteDisposable` shuts down the deletion system.
- Before you assign to the `deleteDisposable`, you should be disposing anything that might be in it. `deleteDisposable?.dispose()`. Otherwise, you will have multiple timers running.
- Whatever `dao` is, if the count of `dao` is being changed from a different thread you have probably set up a race condition with your `map` closure. Closures passed to `map` need to be pure.

Lastly, did you know that timers pause running when the app is in the background?